# How old are Thor, Loki, and Odin (and Asgardians) in Earth years in Marvel movies?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, thor

In MCU movies, Thor, Loki, and Odin are not really gods, if I am right; they are more like an alien race with super powers.

Compared to people on earth, how old are Thor, Loki, Odin, and Asgardians in Earth years? Hundred-thousand years old or more? Are their lives limited? If they don't get killed, will they be considered immortals?

Comment: related: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/14578/how-old-is-thor

Comment: In 1st movie Loki mentions they live 50 times longer then humans, IIRC.

Comment: When Odin is talking about Hela, he says they are millions of years old, which contradicts other parts of the series. This question likely has no answer as far as the MCU.

Comment: In the famed snake story from Ragnarok, Thor states that both he and Loki had been eight at the time. So they're the same age or at least only a year or two apart.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thor_(Marvel_Comics)) article about Thor (so basically the comic version) :

> Like all Asgardians, Thor is incredibly long-lived and relies upon periodic consumption of the Golden Apples of Idunn to sustain his extended lifespan, which to date has lasted **many millennia.**

From [MCU wiki](http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Thor) page in a sidebar there are basic info about Thor (the film version). There we see:

> **Age: Over one thousand years.**
>
> Powers and abilities:
>   [...]Thor trained and skilled in the arts of battle, which he has practiced for **thousands of years.**[...]
>
> **Superhuman Longevity**: Thor, *like all other Asgardians*, is **not truly immortal**. It is possible to kill an Asgardian and other beings in the Nine Realms. More accurately, Asgardians are extremely long-lived beings. Thor ages at a pace far, far slower than a human, as **he is at least 1,000 or more years old**; more than likely, like Loki, born shortly before the last great war between the Asgardians and the Frost Giants.

As for [Loki](http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Loki):

> **Age: 1051-1052**
>
> Powes and abilities:
>   **Superhuman Longevity**: Loki has the capacity to live for thousands of years. Loki was a baby at the end of the last great war between the Asgardians and the Jotuns, over a thousand years ago.

As for [Odin](http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Odin):

> **Age: Thousands of years**.
>
> Powers and abilities:
>   **Superhuman Longevity**: Odin ages at a rate that is much slower than that of a human being. Even though he is thousands of years old, he still in very good health, greatly belying his appearance. When he died, **he was over 5.000 years old if not older**.

## **UPDATE: CONTAINING NEW INFORMATION FROM AVENGERS INFINITY WAR**

In the *Avengers Infinity War*, Thor himself says he is **1500 years old**. 
(I can't find an online transcript at the moment, but I watched the movie yesterday, and he clearly said it.)

Comment: Yes, I can confirm that. I watched the movie too last weekend, and Thor said he is 1500 years old

Answer (score 1):

In *Thor: The Dark World* Odin and Loki have the following exchange:

> **Odin:** We are not gods! We're born, we live, we die, just as humans do.
>   **Loki:** Give or take five thousand years.

Now Loki isn't saying they LIVE for 5000 years.  He's saying they live for some OTHER time, probably longer, with an average deviation of 5000 years.

In *Ragnarok* Thor comments to Surtur "I thought my father killed you half a million years ago".

It's also mentioned outside the MCU that the creation of Mjolnir was what killed the Dinosaurs.

An exact number is gonna be tough to produce but I'm thinking pretty old.

Comment: Welcome to Movies.SE! Just as a heads-up, anything mentioned "outside the MCU" is not relevant to the MCU. There's no indication in the movies that Mjolnir was forged 66 million years ago. I also don't see how this answers the specific question of how old they actually are.

Answer (score 1):

You are right that the Asgardians are more like a highly advanced alien race with superhuman abilities. They do have a lifespan, but it is much longer than that of humans. As Odin says in *Thor: The Dark World*, "*We are not gods! We're born, we live, we die, just as humans do.*" Loki adds, "*Give or take five thousand years.*"

Based on the movies and the official MCU timeline book, we can estimate the ages of some of the main Asgardian characters:

- **Thor:** In *Avengers: Infinity War*, which takes place in 2018, [Thor tells Rocket that he is **1500 years old**](https://youtu.be/N6AVsaJHIOY?t=92).
- **Loki:** According to *[Marvel Studios’ The Marvel Cinematic Universe: An Official Timeline](https://books.google.com/books/about/Marvel_Studios_the_Marvel_Cinematic_Univ.html?id=aeqSzwEACAAJ)*, which provides the official chronology of the MCU events, Odin adopted Loki as a baby around **965 CE**. This means that Loki was roughly 1053 years old in 2018.
  [image]
- **Odin:** In *Thor: Ragnarok*, [Thor mentions to Surtur that he thought Odin had killed Surtur "*half a million years ago*"](https://youtu.be/Y86DgfO0P-c?t=24). This implies that Odin is **approximately 500,000 years old**, including the time he spent in the Odinsleep. The official timeline book states:
  [image: Miss Minutes (text quoted below)]

> REDLINE ALERT!
>
> Hello there! Thor tells Surtur, "I thought my father killed you half a
> million years ago." Now, we know Asgardians live a long time, but do
> they live that long? It's hard to say how long Odin has been around,
> 'cause sometimes he falls into the Odinsleep.

- *[Marvel Studios’ The Marvel Cinematic Universe: An Official Timeline](https://books.google.com/books/about/Marvel_Studios_the_Marvel_Cinematic_Univ.html?id=aeqSzwEACAAJ)*

So, to answer your question, Thor, Loki, Odin, and the Asgardians are very old in Earth years, but not immortal. They can die of old age, or injury, just like humans. This is confirmed by the Time Variance Authority (TVA) (introduced in the *Loki* TV series), the organization that monitors and maintains the main MCU timeline, also known as the “Sacred Timeline”, as their AI mascot, Miss Minutes, explains. From the *Official Timeline*:

[image: Miss Minutes]

> ##### TVA ALERT!
>
> Hey there! How long do Asgardians live? That's a great question! As Odin the Allfather will one day explain, they exist for a very long time but aren't immortal. He says they are born and die just like regular folks, but his son Loki adds: "Give or take 5,000 years." That's a whole lotta wiggle room!

Comment: *"Odin: In Thor: Ragnarok, Thor mentions to Surtur that he thought Odin had killed Surtur "half a million years ago". This implies that Odin is at least 500,000 years old."* << Or it just implies that Thor likes hyperboles. Note the exact line is "I thought my father killed you **, like,** half a million years ago". I think this "like" in the middle doesn't add credence to the rest of the sentence.

Comment: @Stef To clarify the issue, I have updated my answer with some extra details from the Official Timeline.

Answer (score 0):

In the comics, Odin was one of the Avengers of 1Mil BCE. Could be 1mil+

Or, in the movies, it's said that Asgardians live for about 5k years.

Answer (score -1):

In human years Loki is estimated to be around 17, but in Asgardian years he is about 1,000, I'm guessing nothing under 800 though. And as for Thor, I watched Infinity War April 27th, and in one part he says he is 1,500 years old.So either way, they are both pretty old. As for Odin I am not so sure, I'll elaborate on him once I find out more information. And since people haven't been able to make screen caps of Infinity War, because spoilers, I can't find him saying it. I think we'll have to wait a bit until a lot more people have watched it though until we get the screen caps. Until then, we wait. :D

Comment: Hi. Welcome to Movies and TV SE. Although your answer has great potential, it lacks some of the key elements a great answer should have. One being you have no proof to what you've been saying. please read here (*https://movies.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer*) to update your answer and provide a better one. Chrres